# how to prevent adding same data to the list from downdown and reuse it once that data is deleted/edited in MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, duplicates, ef-code-first, crud

[this is the list of my units](https://i.stack.imgur.com/my8QC.jpg)

[this is how I add units to my list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTtEo.jpg)

[This is what I want to prevent "Same Data Selected from Downdown again and again.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkTcK.jpg)

note : shopNumber and Floor are two different table whose ID's are used in the main unit form .

This is my Unit Controller .

```
    public ActionResult AddUnit() //GET UNITS 
    {

        var floors = _Context.Floor.ToList();
        var shops = _Context.Shop.ToList();
        var viewModel = new UnitFormViewModel
        {

            Floors = floors,
            Shops = shops
        };

        return View("AddUnit",viewModel);
    }

    //POST UNITS

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save( Unit Unit)
    {

        if (Unit.Id==0)
        _Context.Unit.Add(Unit);

       else
        {
            var unitInDb = _Context.Unit.Single(c => c.Id == Unit.Id);

            unitInDb.Size = Unit.Size;
            unitInDb.floorId = Unit.floorId;
            unitInDb.shopId = Unit.shopId;
        }

        _Context.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("leaseUnit", "Rent");
    }







    public ActionResult Edit(int id)

    {
        var Unit = _Context.Unit.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);
        if (Unit == null)
            return HttpNotFound();
        var viewModel = new UnitFormViewModel
        {
            Unit=Unit,
           Floors=_Context.Floor.ToList(),
            Shops = _Context.Shop.ToList()


        };
        return View("EditUnit", viewModel);
    }


    //DELETE A UNIT

    public ActionResult Delete(int id)

    {

        _Context.Unit.Remove(_Context.Unit.Find(id));

        _Context.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("unitList", "Home");

    }





}
```

}

This is my Add A Unit into the list View Code :

```html
@model mallform.ViewModel.UnitFormViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddUnit";
}

<h2><strong>Add Unit</strong></h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Unit"))

{

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Unit.Size)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Unit.Size, new { @class = "form-control " })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Unit.Size)
    <br>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Unit.floorId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Unit.floorId, new SelectList(Model.Floors, "Id", "Name"), "",
        new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Unit.floorId)
    <br>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Unit.shopId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Unit.shopId, new SelectList(Model.Shops, "Id", "Name"), "",
        new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Unit.shopId)
    <br>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Unit.Id)

    <br>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>

}
```

Please tell me how to prevent this adding of same data into the list from drop-down menu and reactivating adding of that data after it is edited or deleted .

Comment: Please don't shout, it won't make people help you faster

Comment: 1- Avoid the use of images, so people can copy-paste the content of the question in order to reproduce the problem. 2- Plese dont use caps, it can be considered rude.

Comment: hahaahahah okayy i'm at my workplace rn and need to know this .

Comment: I did this to make it clear, that's it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(_Context.Unit.Any(u => u.Id != Unit.Id && u.shopId == Unit.shopId))
{
    // return because there already exist a Unit with this shopId
}
```

Comment: I will mark this as an answer ,thank you so much :) means alot